# Link to a admin submenu item using a custom link

Tags: plugin-development, admin-menu, customization

**Situation:**

I am developing my first Wordpress plugin with multiple admin pages. This plugin has a menu and some submenus in *Admin Menu*. I am using Wordpress 3.9 on XAMPP, Windows 8.1 Pro.

**Problem:**

What I want to achieve is like *Add New* button (link) which is in *All Posts* page. I mean when one clicks on the *Add New* link in *All Posts* page, they are taken to the *Add New* page itself, with the submenu *Add New* selected.

[image]

Here is my code:

```
function nes_general_settings_view () { 
    echo "In General Settings";
}

function nes_vendor_view () { 
    ?>
    All Vendors <a href="<?=HOW_TO_LINK_TO_nes_vendor_new_view_function?>">Add New Vendor</a>
    <table>
       ...
    </table>
    <?php

}

function nes_vendor_new_view () { 
    echo "In New Vendor";
}

function nes_tell_us_view () {
    echo "In Tell Us";
}


add_action("admin_menu", function () {
add_menu_page(
    "Our Service",   
    "Our Service",           
    "manage_options",            
    "nes_general_settings",      
    "nes_general_settings_view", 
    null,                        
    4                            
);

add_submenu_page( "nes_general_settings", "General Settings", "General Settings", 0, "nes_general_settings", "nes_general_settings_view");

add_submenu_page( "nes_general_settings", "Vendors", "Vendors", 0, "nes_vendor", "nes_vendor_view");
add_submenu_page( "nes_general_settings", "New Vendor", "New Vendor", 0, "nes_vendor_new", "nes_vendor_new_view");

add_submenu_page( "nes_general_settings", "Tell Us", "Tell Us!", 0, "nes_tell_us", "nes_tell_us_view");
```

});

**Question:**

How to generate such a link (in particular `HOW_TO_LINK_TO_nes_vendor_new_view_function` in source code)? Shall I use a special function to generate dynamic contents? And also can you tell me which file generates the *All Posts* admin page, for the sake of reference?

Comment: If you've created a CPT this should be automatic. If you are doing something other than that this question is both too broad and too poorly described to answer.

Comment: Can you add your code that you are using to add the submenu page you would like to link to?

Comment: @Douglas.Sesar: I updated added the source codes and gave more explaination.

Comment: @s_ha_dum Can you tell me what does CPT mean? Also I added more explaination to question.

Comment: CPT is Custom Post Type

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly what you are asking, you need the `$menu_slug` used when adding your menu pages:

```
//add_menu_page( $page_title, $menu_title, $capability, $menu_slug, $function, $icon_url, $position );
//add_submenu_page( $parent_slug, $page_title, $menu_title, $capability, $menu_slug, $function );

$your_link_url = admin_url( 'admin.php?page='.$menu_slug, 'http' );
```

OR SPECIFICALLY FOR YOU

```
$your_link_url = admin_url( 'admin.php?page=nes_vendor_new', 'http' );
```

You can always verify the link by clicking on the menu item and see where it takes you.